# JavaScript code encoded

Tags: javascript, decode, encode, decoding

I have a javascript code but she is encoded i wanna to decode it beacouse i gonna to change the functions so i dont have any idea how is she encoded and how to decode it.

Here is a part of code

```
function updateTitle(_0x3c9303) {
document[_0x305d('0x1b')] = _0x3c9303;
}
```

I tryed with a loot of online decoders but i dont get any results.

I dont have any other idea what type of encode is this `_0x3c9303` i searched in google and in some forums but i dont get anyresults.

Comment: those are hex codepoint unicode characters encoded in UTF-16LE: `_崰('0x1b') = _錼`; the `0x1b` appears to be a hexadecimal number in JavaScript

Comment: Is there any way to decode it ?

Comment: that comment is decoded. The real question is can you work with it decoded? `0x1b === 27dec` or the `esc` key.

Comment: Its any way to contact with you sir i have a big code i need help to decode all of it.

Comment: Will you accept my answer?

Comment: I sorry, but I'm afraid that is not the type of work I do.

Answer (score 0):

Those are Hexidecimal-codepoint Unicode characters encoded in UTF-16LE: 
`_崰('0x1b') = _錼;`

The 0x1b appears to be a hexadecimal number in JavaScript that equates to either the number 27 or the `esc` key.

There are a number of websites that will help you decode this encoding. Google is probably your best bet for that.

This is the site that I used to decode the individual characters:

https://www.mobilefish.com/services/latin_utf_base64_to_hex/latin_utf_base64_to_hex.php#text_hex_output

Comment: @AbedinThaqi - please see my answer - I added a link for you.

Comment: did you read the instructions? The input must be a hexadecimal value; hexidecimal values start with 0 (zero) not underscore ( _ ). Remove the underscore and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, you'll also need to remove the `0x` as well.

Comment: i just getting a dragon icon

Comment: That is not an icon, that is a Unicode character. Best of luck to you, I've answered the question you asked and assisted further. Please accept my answer.